# How to convert lat/lon to correct pixel location in GridLayer Tile

Tags: leaflet, react-leaflet

I'm playing with creating a Konva-based GridLayer for Leaflet (basically an abstraction around canvas elements to try and render tens of thousands of features efficiently). I have some code that seems to work to some degree (the lines in my sample data seem to line up with what I would expect), but I am getting strange behavior. Specifically, features will seem to visibly "teleport" or disappear completely. Additionally, it is not uncommon to see breaks in lines at the edges of the tiles. I suspect this means I'm calculating the pixel location within each tile incorrectly (although it's certainly possible something else is wrong). I am basically identifying the pixel location of the tile (x, y in renderStage()), and am translating the map pixel position by that many pixels (pt.x and pt.y, generated by projecting the lat/lon). This is intended to create an array of [x1, y1, x2, y2, ...], which can be rendered to the individual tile. Everything is expected to be in EPSG:4326.

Does anyone know how to properly project lat/lon to pixel coordinates within individual tiles of a GridLayer? There are plenty of examples for doing it for the entire map, but this doesn't seem to translate cleanly into how to find those same pixel locations in tiles offset from the upper left of the map.

```
import { GridLayer, withLeaflet } from "react-leaflet";
import { GridLayer as LeafletGridLayer } from "leaflet";
import { Stage, Line, FastLayer } from "konva";
import * as Util from 'leaflet/src/core/Util';
import _ from "lodash";

export const CollectionLayer = LeafletGridLayer.extend({
  options: {
    tileSize: 256
  },
  initialize: function(collection, props) {
    Util.setOptions(this, props)
    this.collection = collection;
    this.stages = new Map();
    this.shapes = {};
    this.cached = {};
    this.on('tileunload', (e) => {
      const stage = this.stages[e.coords]
      if (stage) {
        this.stages.delete(e.coords)
        stage.destroy()
      }
    })
  },
  renderStage: function(stage, coords, tileBounds) {
    const x = coords.x * this._tileSize.x
    const y = coords.y * this._tileSize.y
    const z = coords.z;
    const layer = stage.getLayers()[0]

    if (!layer || !tileBounds) return;
    _.each(this.collection.data, (entity, id) => {
      if (entity.bounds && tileBounds.intersects(entity.bounds)) {
        let shape = this.shapes[id]
        if (!shape) {
          shape = new Line()
          shape.shadowForStrokeEnabled(false)
          this.shapes[id] = shape
        }
        layer.add(shape);
        const points = entity.position.reduce((pts, p) => {
          const pt = this._map.project([p.value[1], p.value[0]], this._tileZoom)
          pts.push(pt.x - x);
          pts.push(pt.y - y);
          return pts
        }, [])
        shape.points(points);
        shape.stroke('red');
        shape.strokeWidth(2);
        this.shapes[id] = shape
      }
    })
    layer.batchDraw()
  },
  createTile: function(coords) {
    const tile = document.createElement("div");
    const tileSize = this.getTileSize();
    const stage = new Stage({
      container: tile,
      width: tileSize.x,
      height: tileSize.y
    });
    const bounds = this._tileCoordsToBounds(coords);
    const layer = new FastLayer();
    stage.add(layer);
    this.stages[coords] = stage
    this.renderStage(stage, coords, bounds);
    return tile;
  }
});

class ReactCollectionLayer extends GridLayer {
  createLeafletElement(props) {
    console.log("PROPS", props);
    return new CollectionLayer(props.collection.data, this.getOptions(props));
  }
  updateLeafletElement(fromProps, toProps) {
    super.updateLeafletElement(fromProps, toProps);
    if (this.leafletElement.collection !== toProps.collection) {
      this.leafletElement.collection = toProps.collection
      this.leafletElement.redraw();
    }
  }
}

export default withLeaflet(ReactCollectionLayer);
```

Answer (score 0):

> Everything is expected to be in EPSG:4326.

No.

Once you are dealing with raster data (image tiles), everything is expected to be either in the map's display CRS, which is (by default) EPSG:3857, or in pixels relative to the CRS origin. These concepts are explained a bit more in-depth in [one of Leaflet's tutorials](https://leafletjs.com/examples/extending/extending-2-layers.html).

In fact, you seem to be working in pixels here, at least for your points:

> ```
> const pt = this._map.project([p.value[1], p.value[0]], this._tileZoom)
> ```

However, your calculation of the pixel offset for each tile is too naïve:

> ```
> const x = coords.x * this._tileSize.x
> const y = coords.y * this._tileSize.y
> ```

That should instead rely on the *private* method `_getTiledPixelBounds` of `L.GridLayer`, e.g.:

```
const tilePixelBounds = this._getTiledPixelBounds();
const x = tilePixelBounds.min.x;
const y = tilePixelBounds.min.y;
```

And use these bounds to add some sanity checks while looping through the points:

```
const pt = this._map.project([p.value[1], p.value[0]], this._tileZoom);
if (!tilePixelBounds.contains(pt)) { console.error(....); }
```

---

On the other hand:

> [...] an abstraction around canvas elements to try and render tens of thousands of features efficiently

I don't think using Konva to actually draw items on a `<canvas>` is going to improve the performance - the methods are just the same used by Leaflet (and, if we're talking about tiling vector data, the same used by [Leaflet.VectorGrid](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.VectorGrid) ). Ten thousand calls to canvas draw functions are going to take the same time no matter what the library on top. If you have time to consider other alternatives, [Leaflet.GLMarkers](https://gitlab.com/IvanSanchez/Leaflet.GLMarkers) and its WebGL rendering might offer better performance at the price of less compatibility and higher integration costs.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clearer, when I say everything is expected to be EPSG:4326, I meant that I had the map configured to use that, and the actual data I am rendering uses that (my code here is intended to convert those to pixels for rendering). I tried your code for calculating x and, and ran into 2 issues. 1) It seems to require a center latlng to be passed in (I used this._map.getCenter()). Without it, I get latlng is undefined while it tries to project it within that method. 2) When I pass the map center, the rendered data is all over the place and not where I expect it, with most tiles blank.